# sorting linked list of string

Tags: c++, linked-list

Im trying to find a way to sort alphabetically a linked list of strings. This is what I have so far, it compiles but crashes when executing.. I have been working at it for hours but cant seem to figure it out. The cout in the while loop commands prints out so i guess it is comparing fine. I feel like its the linking that I am messing up.. This is schoolwork btw, so any input is welcome! its ordreAlpha that (supposed to) sorts the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>


struct Espion
{
    std:: string name; /* nom de l’espion(ne) */
    Espion *next; /* pointeur sur le prochain espion */
} ;


Espion *sortAlpha(Espion*ptr)
{
   Espion *cur = ptr;
   Espion *tempo = NULL;
   Espion *prev  = NULL;
   Espion *first  = ptr;
   Espion *last  = NULL;
   bool flag;

   do{

    flag = false;
    while(cur->next != NULL){
                    tempo = cur->next;
                    if(cur->name.compare(tempo->name) > 0){

                           flag = true;// needs swap
                           cur->next = tempo->next;
                           tempo->next = cur;
                           if(prev != NULL)
                                   prev->next = tempo;


                           if(prev == NULL)
                                   first = tempo;

                           if(cur->next == NULL)
                                   last = cur; 

                           prev = cur; 
                           cur = cur->next;
                           delete tempo;       
                    }
                    else {

                         prev = cur;
                         cur = cur->next;
                    }

         }
      delete cur;
      delete prev;
      cur = first;              
    }while(flag == true);  

    return first;             
}







void printList(Espion* ptr)
{
     std::cout << "\n"<< std::endl;
     while(ptr){
                std::cout << ptr-> name << std::endl;
                ptr = ptr->next;
     }
     std::cout << "\n"<< std::endl;

}

int main()
{

    char fileName[] = "espion.txt";

    std:: string infoEspion;


    Espion *cur = NULL;
    Espion *first = NULL;
    Espion *last = NULL;
    Espion *add = NULL;


    std :: ifstream readFile;
    readFile.open(fileName, std::ios::in);

    if(!readFile.is_open()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }





    while(std::getline(readFile, infoEspion))
    {
                if(first == NULL){ //head
                      add = new Espion;
                      add -> name = infoEspion.substr(0,30);
                      add -> next = NULL;
                      first = add;
                      cur = add;
                      last = add;


                      }
                      else
                      if(trouverNomListe(first, infoEspion.substr(0,30)) == false ) // adding only if not on the list already

                            {

                                add = new Espion;
                                add -> name = infoEspion.substr(0,30);
                                add -> next = NULL;
                                cur -> next = add;
                                last = add;
                                cur = add;



                             }








    }
    printList(first);


    printList(sortAlpha(first));

    readFile.close();


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should use a debugger to step through your code and find out the origins of your problem, and narrow it to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posing here. Plain code dumps aren't accepted well.

Comment: Also please translate your program to English. It's not quite clear what `afficherListe` and `trouverNomListe` are.

Comment: Instead of `ptr->nom.compare(nomAChercher) == 0` why not `ptr->non == nonAChercher`. Why not pass `nonAChercher` by const reference to avoid copying it? Instead of `char nomFichier[50] = "espion.txt";` why not `char nomFichier[] = "espion.txt";`

Comment: You never delete your nodes so you have memory leaks.

Comment: @Anton that's a fantastic comment, and a lesson to all to select meaningful variable names. No more i, ii, iii, then reuse them mid-function!

Comment: @Dinesh And what? You're missing the point ... (and _@Anton_ does as well)

Comment: @NeilKirk thanks, that does look better. I dont have all the right habits yet..

Comment: so yes debugger send me access violation error

Comment: @Dinesh I don't understand your comment.

Comment: and i will translate it, its that my class is in french... i dont have a choice but to use french variables

Comment: And you have to finish this paper till tomorow? Isn't it midnight in Paris?

Comment: not paris, montreal.. around 6 oclock, but id like to get it done for tomorrow..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ note the "also" in my comment - it refers to yours. What I meant was "make an MCVE and translate it into English".

Comment: There's no Canada like French Canada, its the best Canada in the land!

Comment: I have just edited the post to a shorter and translated version, but all connected to the sorting is there. I hope this is better..

Comment: @Neil and πάντα ῥεῖ, with all due respect -- when I read the comment I can see it is totally easy to misunderstand - even I don't get it!!!! Apologies there. What I had meant to say (and my mother tongue too isn't English) is that variable names are supposed to convey meaning to another human reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second time around your `do .. while` loop, `prec` will still have its previous value (the end of the list), so when you find you have to swap again, it will link the end of your list with the `tempo`. To fix this, reset `prec` to NULL at the top of the `do .. while` loop.

You should also check that `ptr` isn't NULL when `ordreAlpha` is called as you are currently immediately checking `cour->suivant` when `cour` may be NULL.

Edit: After debugging, another problem is that when you swap nodes, you also then do `cur = cur->next`, which can lead to `cur` being `NULL` whihc will cause a fault in your look condition `cur->next != NULL`. In this case (when you have swapped) you don't want to move `cur` on to the next node. Instead, you just need to ensure that `prev` is set to the correct value and let your loop continue with the current node.

In your case, just change

```
prev = cur; 
cur = cur->next;
delete tempo;
```

to

```
prev = tempo;
```

Comment: so i delete the nodes on top of do...while and i checked and ptr isnt NULL.. but still crashes..

Comment: No, don't delete any nodes. You are sorting, so you need to keep the same number of nodes. Just add `prec = NULL` at the top of your loop, or at the bottom, just after `cour = prem`.

Comment: But now the debugger is giving me something more : while = not found in current context. That and the access violation

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - is the the debugger saying while = not found, or the compiler?

Comment: yes! I finally see what my mistake was.. It runs good now, thank you so much for time

Answer (score 0):

Your sortAlpha function does not allocate anything so any delete statements in there is fishy and will probably lead to crashes later on

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid those if statements that check for prev == NULL by using a pointer to pointer:

```
Espion **pprev;              // pointer to cur or previous node's next pointer
    // ...
    cur = first;             // init current pointer (before the do while loop)
    // ...
    pprev = &cur;            // init pprev (before the inner while loop)
    // ...
    *pprev = tempo;          // update what was pointing to cur
    pprev = &(tempo->next);  // update what prev points to
```